# Multi AJAX Request in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-7

Goodtime
I write this code but when i send for database only submit one query "sad" !
çi use
`$request->has('happy') or ...` no working
Can anyone help me?
for sample
**`$request->has('happy')` ** `submit 'happy' or **$request->has('love')` ** submit 'love'
I'm tired of searching
thanks to stackoverflow and members

```
 <form method="post">
                                {{csrf_field()}}

                                <button type="submit" value="happy" id="happy" class="border-0 btn-submit">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/reactions/happy.png" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" value="angry" id="angry" class="border-0 btn-submit">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/reactions/angry.png" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" value="ill" id="ill" class="border-0 btn-submit">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/reactions/ill.png" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" value="love" id="love" class="border-0 btn-submit">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/reactions/in-love.png" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" value="quiet" id="quiet" class="border-0 btn-submit">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/reactions/quiet.png" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" value="sad" id="sad" class="border-0 btn-submit">
                                    <img src="/assets/images/reactions/sad.png" />
                                </button>
                                <!-- <input type="text" name="studentName" id="studentName" class="form-control" placeholder="please type in your name"> -->

                                <input type="hidden" value="{{$article->id}}" id="post_id">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">

                            </form>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $.ajaxSetup({
                                    headers: {
                                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                                    }
                                });

                                $(".btn-submit").click(function(e) {

                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
                                    var sad = $("#sad").val();
                                    var quiet = $("#quiet").val();
                                    var love = $("#love").val();
                                    var ill = $("#ill").val();
                                    var angry = $("#angry").val();
                                    var happy = $("#happy").val();



                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: "{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
                                        data: {
                                            post_id: post_id,
                                            sad: sad,
                                            quiet: quiet,
                                            love: love,
                                            ill: ill,
                                            angry: angry,
                                            happy: happy
                                        },

                                        success: function(data) {
                                            alert(data.success);

                                        }
                                    });

                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Reaction;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function ajaxRequest()
    {
        return view('ajaxRequest');
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function ajaxRequestPost(Request $request, Reaction $reaction)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        \Log::info($input);
        if ($request->ajax()) {


            if (!Auth::user()) {   // Check is user logged in
                $must_login = "you must login";
                return response()->json(['success' => $must_login]);
            } else {

                $date = date('Y-m-d');
                $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $output = "Your reaction Submited";
                $post_id = $request->input('post_id');
                // Checker
                $checker = Reaction::select('*')->where([
                    ['post_id', '=', $post_id],
                    ['user_id', '=', $user_id],
                    ['date', '=', $date]
                ])->first();
                if ($checker == null) {








                    if ($request->has('sad') == true) {
                        Reaction::create([
                            'user_id' => $user_id,
                            'post_id' => $post_id,
                            'reaction' => 'sad',
                            'date' => $date,
                        ]);
                    } elseif ($request->has('love')) {
                        Reaction::create([
                            'user_id' => $user_id,
                            'post_id' => $post_id,
                            'reaction' => 'love',
                            'date' => $date,
                        ]);
                    } else {
                        echo "fuck";
                    }

                    return response()->json(['success' => $output]);
                } else {
                    return response()->json(['success' => 'You Befor Submited Your Rection']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `$(".btn-submit").click(function(e) {` to `$(".btn-submit").on('click', function(e) {` and see what it gives. If it works, I'll give an answer below.

Comment: Hi thanks but no working [link](https://ibb.co/ZS9j8kL) add sad again

Comment: Ok, Your form is a bit unusual but it should work. Try `$("form").on('submit', function(e) {` because it daunted to me that buttons don't send the form. They trigger the form, You should find the button value in `$('.btn-submit').val();`. Together with `user_id` this is all the information you'll need for the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
    var reaction = $(".btn-submit").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('ajaxRequest.post') }}",
        data: { post_id, reaction },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

```
public function ajaxRequestPost(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks i use this ,  give me this "[object Object]"

Comment: Yes of course. Inside the object you'll see what you've send to the server. I echo back what your server received. Change `alert(data)` to `console.log(data);` first! Click ctrl+shift+k, try it again and click on the object you get back.The right tab of the console will show you what is inside this object. You'll find id, the reaction and the _token. Then you know what to do with this information in your Controller. I can't write this for you. This is a 'skeleton' to help you to continue writing your code..

Comment: thnak you very very much for your help , i am change to "console.log(data);" but no noting answer no in page view no in "laravel.log" but for this "alert(data)" working .

Comment: It doesn't log in Laravel log, but in your (js) console. You'll see it if you click ctrl+shift+k or ctrl+shift+j. It's a handy helper if you are working with js and especially ajax. Once you get the hang of it, you'll use it all the time. Promise! Please read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console to help you further.

Comment: thanks very much for your help , give me this answer [link](https://ibb.co/Yjy9fTM)

Comment: Please consider to mark my answer as correct so you can close this issue.

Comment: thanks very much , im very try but no working for me .

Comment: You're new. No problem my friend. It's simple really. Please read this. So if you ask more questions, don't hesitate to do so. Stackoverflow is here to help. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work